How to set an Icon (MaterialIcons) using its code_point in Flutter?
I'm currently trying to load dynamically icons from a Supabase table "markers_info" that contains, among other things, icons (their name and their code_point), into markers to display on a map.



id
type
icon_code
color_hex




1
Monument
e84f
#D5B92D


2
Museum
e8f4
#EFA31F


3
Bar
e563
#AD1F1F


...
...
...
...



I'm successfully loading their colors, but I'm struggling to load their icons:
for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
  final type = types[i];
  final markerIcon = typeData[type]?['icon_code'] != null
      ? IconData(typeData[type]['icon_code'], fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')
      : Icons.place;
  final markerColor = typeData[type]?['color'] != null
      ? Color(int.parse('0xff' + typeData[type]['color'].substring(1)))
      : Colors.red;

It's likely that my code regarding icons is incorrect, but I'm not sure how to write it so that Flutter will load icons from their code_point (for instance, for the icon "Castle", the code_point would be eab1: Material Symbols Outlined: castle).
Thank you for your help!

Convert icon code point string to int
int codePoint = int.tryParse(item['icon_code'] ?? '', radix: 16) ?? 0xe88a;
and use like...  IconData(
codePoint,
              ),


Found a solution (like always, 5 minutes after asking this question).
I used the hex code from this repo: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/flutter/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/icons.dart
and adapted the code as follows:
for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
  final type = types[i];
  final markerIcon = typeData[type]?['icon'] != null
      ? IconData(int.parse(typeData[type]['icon'], radix: 16),
          fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')
      : Icons.place;
  final markerColor = typeData[type]?['color'] != null
      ? Color(int.parse('0xff' + typeData[type]['color'].substring(1)))
      : Colors.red;

So for "Castle", it's actually "0xf04cb". Make sure to remove the 0x beforehand (so "f04cb").
